# How to check whether record is delete or not in ROOM Database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, androidx

**Using SQLite DB,**

**db.delete** will return a long value that is the row ID of new row, or **-1** if an error occurred.
So you can check it to know delete is successful or not by :

```
int result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
if(result != -1){
  // Deleted successful
}
```

But , in  **ROOM DB**

we can delete record by :

```
 @Delete
 void delete(Notes notes);
```

Is there any option to check whether record deleted or not ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-delete

The URL suggests that you can return an Int value from the delete method but it returns the number of rows it has deleted in that operation. 
But other than that, you can query the DB once again for the record you are looking to confirm whether its deleted or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply define an `Int` return type to the `@Delete` method. The returned `Int` would be the numbers of rows deleted. (`0` if nothing deleted)

### Example

**ProductsDao.kt**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface ProductsDao {

    /**
     * To delete one or more products.
     * Returns number of rows deleted. 0 if no row deleted.
     */
    @Delete
    fun delete(vararg products: Product): Int // This is what you want

}
```

and I'd check if the row is deleted like this

```kotlin
// one row
val isDeleted = productsDao.delete(product) == 1

// multiple rows
val isDeleted = productsDao.delete(productList) == productList.size
```